# Access td with class on row open

Tags: javascript, footable

I have a [footable](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/jsdocs/index.html)
. When I click on the plus to expand a row

[image]

I want to access with jQuery the yellow elements:

[image]

If I inspect the element the DOM looks like that after the click:

```
<table class="footable-details table">
   <tbody>
      <tr><th>
        DOB (hide)
      </th><td style="display: table-cell;">
        10/16/1977
      </td></tr><tr><th>
       Description
      </th><td class="someText" style="display: table-cell;">
        Some description
      </td></tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

What I would like to do, is to set `colspan="2"` for `td.someText` and hide the `<th>Description</th>`. But I can't access `td.someText`

I tried to access it with

```
$('.footable').on('expand.ft.row', function(e, ft, row){
     $(row.$details).find('td.someText'));    
});
```

but he does not find anything. In fact, `alert($(row.$details).html());` only returns

```
<td colspan="4">
    <table class="footable-details table">
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

Any idea how to access the td with class `someText` after click?

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwk39vqj/3/)

---

Note: This is not a duplicate of [Footable and capturing the expand row event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807205/footable-and-capturing-the-expand-row-event). The linked question is about how to access a row in general. This question is if I select it with the method from the API the content is not loaded correctly. The question helped me to get here, but does not to solve the here presented issue.

Comment: when you click expand content is not there.it is added after you click on it.so if you wait little time you can get the content.but best way is to use content load event if available. https://jsfiddle.net/dbc1fzvw/1/

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha omgosh thank you. How do you use content load? I think waiting 200ms may not always be reliable?

Comment: yes it could take less or more.so you should check if is there any api methods available for after expand event.

Comment: i just read the github source code and found the correct event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expand.ft.row` event fires before it appends the dom content.so if you try to read the row content, it's not there.

The correct event for your case is `expanded.ft.row` which fires after appending the content.

```
  $('.footable').on('expanded.ft.row', function(e, ft, row) {
    alert($(row.$details).html());
  });
```

check this demo
https://jsfiddle.net/bfmaredn/

I found this event by analyzing the source code from GitHub repository https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/blob/V3/src/js/classes/FooTable.Row.js

Answer (score 0):

Use "async function", try the following code:

```
$(function() {
 $(".footable").footable();
 $('.footable').on('expand.ft.row', async function(e, ft, row) {
  alert($(await row.$details).html());
 });
});
```

Refer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function